# Div not auto expanding due to dynamically loaded content

Tags: php, html, sql, css

I have a bit of an issue...

Ive made a div, and normally, it expands to suit the height of its contents fine, however... Now i have a problem.

My content is being returned from a Sql statment, and its not expanding to suit its height, a working non dynamic version is

```
#commentblock {
    min-height:50px;
    width:90%;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #999;
}
```

My code is as follows (its in a for loop making a new div for each instance)

```
// Now lets query to grab the responses to this fault
$querytwo = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE faultid=".$fid;

// execute query
$resulttwo = mysql_query($querytwo) or die ("Error in query: $querytwo. ".mysql_error());

// see if any rows were returned
if (mysql_num_rows($resulttwo) > 0) {
    // print them one after another
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($resulttwo)) {
        // lets make this render then
        echo "<div id='commentblock'>";
        echo "<div class='loggedby'>Logged By : <span>".$row[4]."</span><p class='contactno'>Entered : <span>".$row[3]."</span></p></div>";
        echo "<div class='info'><span>".$row[2]."</span></div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }       
}

// free result set memory
mysql_free_result($resulttwo);

// close connection
mysql_close($connection);
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, the content was in a span which was inheriting a floating attribute. Removed the float - now its all fine :)

Answer (score -1):

It might not be to do with dynamic code, but invalid HTML.

You are using:

```
id='commentblock'
```

... in a loop, which create multiple, identical IDs on the same page, which is not valid.

You should change to:

```
class='commentblock'
```

and reference you CSS as:

```
.commentblock
```

... instead of:

```
#commentblock
```

Comment: `but invalid HTML` what is invalid?

Comment: Nothings invalid. Not quite sure what he was on about. XHTML checked the lot. no errors. Its just the way CSS assigns things absolutely, doesnt make it invalid by any means!

Comment: o! i know. it's really not so good to create multiple divs with one id. it will cause problems for `getElementById` js function